# PasswordFiled char[] to String in Java connection MySql?

Tags: java

This is a jFrame to connect to the database and this is in the button connect. My issue is in the passwordField NetBeans make me do a char[], but my .getConnection not let me insert the char[]  ERROR: "no suitable method found for getConnection(String,String,char[])". So I will change to String right? So when I change and run the jFrame said access denied. when I start doing the System.out.println(l) " Give me the right answer" Like this: "Alex". But when I do the System.out.println(password) "Give me the Array spaces and not the value"
Like this: jdbc:mysql://localhost/home inventory  root    [C@5be5ab68 <--- Array space . What I doing wrong?

```
 try {
    Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver"); //Load the driver

    String host = "jdbc:mysql://"+tServerHost.getText()+"/"+tSchema.getText();

        String uName = tUsername.getText();
        char[] l =  pPassword.getPassword();
        System.out.println(l);
        String password= l.toString();

        System.out.println(host+uName+password);
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, password);
        System.out.println(host+uName+password);
    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex.getMessage());
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert an char[] to a string just create a new String with passing char[] as an argument to the constructor. [new String(char[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28char%5B%5D%29)

```
char[] l = pPassword.getPassword();
String s = new String(l);
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: Work very good I was doing this before: String s = new String(char[l]); I don't what I was thinking. Thanks